# CircleCI : configuring the test of Docker container hosted on gcp

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, circleci

I'm setting up a continuous deployment process with CircleCI, targeting Google Container Engine. I'm following [this documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/continuous-deployment-with-google-container-engine/), alongside [this example](https://github.com/circleci/docker-hello-google).

I'm stucked at this stage:

```
test:
  post:
    - docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -e "SECRET_KEY_BASE=${SECRET_KEY}" eu.gcr.io/${PROJECT_NAME}/${MAIN_CONTAINER_NAME}:latest; sleep 10
    - curl --retry 10 --retry-delay 5 -v http://localhost:3000
```

This is a simple test, verifying that my docker image is able to answer to an http request. I get this result after the curl:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:3000/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused

curl --retry 10 --retry-delay 5 -v http://localhost:3000 returned exit code 7
```

The same command works if i'm trying it in my local shell. I get this result locally:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:3000/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I don't get the reason of this difference.

Comment: I  also asked this question on the [CircleCI Discuss](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/configuring-the-test-of-docker-container-hosted-on-googlecontainerengine/12395)

Comment: Why isn't someone from circleci looking at this ?

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing this would be first to start your container with a name as well:

`docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -e "SECRET_KEY_BASE=${SECRET_KEY}" --name ${MAIN_CONTAINER_NAME} eu.gcr.io/${PROJECT_NAME}/${MAIN_CONTAINER_NAME}:latest; sleep 10`

Then replace the curl task with this run of a curl container:

`docker run --network container:${MAIN_CONTAINER_NAME} appropriate/curl --retry 10 --retry-delay 5 -v http://172.17.0.2`

**Additional explanations:**

`--network container:${MAIN_CONTAINER_NAME}` - will attach the curl container to the network of the MAIN_CONTAINER_NAME container, which by default would be in the range of `172.17.0.0/16`

`http://172.17.0.2` - since the MAIN_CONTAINER_NAME is the first container created within that Docker network, it will have the `172.17.0.2` IP address, with the host machine being on `.1` and the curl container on `.3`